# Is it possible to redirect the python output to web by using 'sys.stdout' command?

Tags: python, django, redirect, web

Is it possible to redirect the python output to web by using the redirecting command?
I know that we can redirect the output like this

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open('file', 'w')
print 'test'
```

or

In terminal like this

```
$ python foo.py > file
```

I heard the `'Django' and 'Flask'` like web framework can do the trick. I wonder whether by using a simple command like  `sys.stdout` can redirect the output to web?

Comment: no, because you have no web address in the standard output

Comment: @Coder55 is `generic views` fine for this?   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-simple-redirect-to

Comment: Setup your script as CGI script/module in your webserver and access it from your browser. Its works fine as you expected.

Comment: Checkout this https://docs.python.org/2/howto/webservers.html

Answer (score 0):

One cool trick you can do as a quick-and-dirty hack to quickly access the output of your python script from the web is redirect it to `nc` with the `-l` (listen) option, like this:

```
python foo.py | nc -l 8080
```

You can then go to `localhost:8080` in your web browser to see the output. It's not really a web server though -- it only works one time! Once someone loads the page, it will stop serving requests.

As a slightly more advanced variant of this that allows visiting the page more than once, wrap it in a loop, something like:

```
while true; do python foo.py | nc -l 8080; done
```

That'll re-run your script every time you refresh the page though! As one final layer of sophistication, you can cache the result so it doesn't need to be recomputed each time:

```
python foo.py > /tmp/myoutput; while true; do nc -l 8080 < /tmp/myoutput; done
```

Obviously none of these are real production-quality solutions, you should use a proper web framework like Flask etc., but they can do the trick if you just want to quickly test something out.